# My WCF service (SOAP 1.2) is not compatible for my consumer (SOAP 1.1)

Tags: wcf, soap

I have a .NET 4.0 WCF service with SOAP 1.2. At least I believe it is 1.2 since in my wsdl it shows the following line:

```
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
```

My service is configured as follows (web.config):

```
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
                <binaryMessageEncoding/>
                <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="FooBar">
            <endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding" contract="IFooBarService" />
        </service>
    </services>
```

Now, my consumer who tries to access my service using SOAP 1.1 told me that his adapter uses **text/xml** but my service is expecting **application/soap+msbin1**.

HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'

What can I do to let my 1.1 consumers use my service (as well as my 1.2 consumers)?

Thank you. (I'm not that much into WCF yet.)

Comment: Add a `basicHttpBinding`.

Comment: I see. BasicHttpBinding is for SOAP 1.1. Okay. How would I configure my service to allow both 1.1 and 1.2?

Comment: Might got a solution, will try it tomorrow: http://blog.allanglen.com/2010/04/wcf-interoperability-with-soap-1-1-and-soap-1-2-clients

Comment: Yeah it's as simple as adding a `<endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="..." />` endpoint to your service.